# Can we run Qt6 examples on Windows 11 vmware?

Tags: qt6, windows-11, vmware-player

Can you run Qt6 apps/examples on Windows 11 vmware? I tried some Qt6 examples but it just shows the window without UI. The app/examples can run well with Qt6 on my physical machine.
Ex: I tried coffee app in Qt 6.3 on Windows 11 vmware.
Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Is 2d/3d acceleration enabled in settings?

Comment: I don't know this. I used default settings for all. Are you asking about VMware settings? Or the Windows 11 settings?

Comment: settings of vmware virtual machine

Comment: I don't see this setting in my vmware.

Comment: I am using VMWare Workstation Pro 16. The 3D acceleration setting is on the VM --> Settings tab. Then under Display the top tickbox item is the 3D Graphics option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relate to this bug https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Critical-BUG-with-rendering-engine-on-Windows-11-Guest/td-p/2886013
I resolved by unchecked 3D Acceleration on the VM settings tab.